# Is $B\mathbb{G}_m$ strongly $A^1$-invariant?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, motivic-cohomology

I have just seen the definition of strongly ${A}_1$ invariance:

> A sheaf of group $G$ is strongly $A_1$ invariance , if both $H^0(-;G)$ and $H^1(-;G)$ is $A_1$-invariant.

I haven't got too much about the point of this definition and just try to think about some examples. Can someone give me some simple examples? Is $B\mathbb{G}_m$ strongly $A_1$-invariant where $\mathbb{G}_m$ is the multiplicative group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of the notion is that for a strongly $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariant sheaf of groups $G$ the classifying space $BG$ is $\mathbb{A}^1$-local. The characterization in terms of $H^0$ and $H^1$ is equivalent to that since $H^0(-,G)$ and $H^1(-,G)$ are the homotopy presheaves $\pi_1$ and $\pi_0$ of $BG$ in the homotopy theory of simplicial Nisnevich sheaves, with all other homotopy presheaves trivial.

The sheaf $\mathbb{G}_m$ is a simple example of a strongly $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariant sheaf of groups (since $\mathbb{G}_m$ and ${\rm Pic}$ are $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariant, assuming we are over a regular base). Over a field, other examples of strongly $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariant sheaves are the sheaves $\mathbf{K}^{\rm M}_n$ of Milnor K-groups. The space $B\mathbb{G}_m$ in the question isn't a sheaf of groups, so strictly speaking the notion doesn't apply.

Of course, the tautological examples are the $\mathbb{A}^1$-fundamental group sheaves, by the theory in Morel's book "$\mathbb{A}^1$-algebraic topology over a field". More examples can be found there. Section 7.3 of the book also contains an example of a strongly $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariant sheaf of groups which is not abelian, namely $\pi_1^{\mathbb{A}^1}(\mathbb{P}^1)$. Most of the examples of strongly $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariant sheaves are actually abelian, but that's mostly due to our lack of knowledge of how to compute $\mathbb{A}^1$-fundamental groups of things.

Comment: $B\mathbb G_m$ can still be viewed as a sheaf of non-discrete groups, and as such it is strongly $\mathbb A^1$-invariant in the sense that $BB\mathbb G_m$ is $\mathbb A^1$-local.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that for $G$ nonabelian, the condition on $H^0$ and $H^1$ is in general *weaker* than the condition that $BG$ is $\mathbb A^1$-local. The latter is actually the correct definition of strong $\mathbb A^1$-invariance (it is what's implicitly used in Morel's book).

Comment: @MarcHoyois From a proof that motivic homotopy theory is not a model topos I see that $G\simeq \Omega L_{A_1}L_{Nis} BG$  iff $G$ is strongly $A_1$-invariant for $G$ a sheaf of groups. I also know that the above holds for $G=B\mathbb{G}_m$. But since $B\mathbb{G}_m$ is not discrete. I wonder if the statement only holds for discrete group object?

Comment: @Alexis If $G$ is a Nisnevich sheaf of ∞-groups, then $G\simeq\Omega L_{\mathbb A^1}L_{nis} BG$ is equivalent to $L_{nis}BG \simeq L_{\mathbb A^1}L_{nis} BG$, which by definition means that $BG$ is $\mathbb A^1$-local.

Comment: @MarcHoyois  Is there an easy proof that $BBG_m$ is $A^1$-local?

Comment: @Alexis By a (highly nontrivial) theorem of Morel, an $A^1$-invariant Nisnevich sheaf of ∞-groups is strongly $A^1$-invariant if and only if its $\pi_0$ is. In particular any $A^1$-invariant connected Nisnevich sheaf of ∞-groups (such as $Pic$) is strongly $A^1$-invariant. There might be a more elementary proof.

Comment: @MarcHoyois Can you give me some reference about the theorem you mentioned please? Is there a way to generalise the results for sheaf of sets to sheaf of $\infty$-groups?

Comment: @Alexis It is Theorem 3.1.12 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.05248.pdf.